# Micronaut is giving logging error when trying to create SNS client

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, micronaut-aws

Steps to reproduce:

1. mn create-app example.micronaut.complete --features aws-api-gateway-graal
2. add dependency implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:1.11.656'
3. modify index() function which was automatically created by mn-cli

```java
@Get("/ping")
    public String index() { //automatically created by mn-cli
        AmazonSNS sns = AmazonSNSClient.builder() //Create SNS client
                .withRegion("ap-south-1").build(); //Specify Region
        return "{\"pong\":true, \"graal\": true}";// to check whether function is working
    }
```

4. ./sam-local.sh
5. http://localhost:3000/ping

I got following error and then function timeout:

> Invocation with requestId [21a6b1d0-7697-12b0-f4d8-d15e16954a4c] failed: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
>                       at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.class$(LogFactory.java:1021)
>                       at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.(LogFactory.java:1674)

Comment: is there some documentation for doing this in kotlin? 
I'm trying to pusblish messages to a aws sns topic from my app

Answer (score 0):

Just add `commons-logging` dependency to your pom.xml or build.gradle:

```
/build.gradle:
dependencies {
   .
   ..
   compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
}
```

```
/pom.xml:
...
<dependencies>
   .
   ..
   <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version>
   </dependency>

</dependencies>
```